# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' in AWS ECS Contnr

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, amazon-ecs

I am trying to deploy a spring boot application (With Aurora-postgresSQL) in AWS ECS container. But
Getting

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer'.

The same code is running fine in my local and also running well in the Docker container in my machine.
It is failing only when I am trying to deploy in AWS ECS Container. Not sure what is missing for AWS.

```
"@timestamp": "",
"@version": "1",
"message": "local-pool - Exception during pool initialization.",
"logger_name": "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool",
"thread_name": "main",
"level": "ERROR",
"level_value": 40000,
"stack_trace": "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:354)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:253)\n\tat org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434)\n\tat org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)\n\tat $$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$dataSource$0(<generated>)\n\tat $$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>)\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258)\n\tat org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)\n\tat $$SpringCGLIB$$0.dataSource(<generated>)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:645)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:548)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293)\n\tat 
\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)\nCaused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:283)\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:309)\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)\n\tat java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:161)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:128)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:113)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:73)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:465)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:589)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:191)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:258)\n\t

"@timestamp": "",
"@version": "1",
"message": "Application run failed",
"logger_name": "org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication",
"thread_name": "main",
"level": "ERROR",
"level_value": 40000,
"stack_trace": "org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'datasource' defined in class path resource : Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to initialize pool: The connection attempt failed.\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:548)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293)\n\tat \n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)\nCaused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'datasource' defined in class path resource : Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to initialize pool: The connection attempt failed.\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:645)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)\n\t... 29 common frames omitted\nCaused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to initialize pool: The connection attempt failed.\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)\n\t... 43 common frames omitted\nCaused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: The connection attempt failed.\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:596)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:582)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)\n\tat $$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$dataSource$0(<generated>)\n\tat $$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>)\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258)\n\tat org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)\n\tat (<generated>)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139)\n\t... 44 common frames omitted\nCaused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:354)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:253)\n\tat org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434)\n\tat org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)\n\t... 57 common frames omitted\nCaused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:283)\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:309)\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)\n\tat java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:161)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:128)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:113)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:73)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:465)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:589)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:191)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:258)`
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>42.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

application.yml

```
datasource:
    hikari:
      username:  **
      jdbc-url: **
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
      schema: **
      connection-test-query: **
      pool-name: local-pool
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      max-lifetime: 30000`
```

Here my Docker script that builds image.

```
# Use Managed Base Image Oracle JDK 17
FROM containerregistry/baseimages/oracle-jdk:17-stable

# URL to get source code for building the image (string)
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.source="https://${REPO_HOSTNAME}/projects/${PROJECT}/repos/${REPO}/browse?at=${COMMIT_HASH}"

# Source control revision identifier for the packaged software. Hash of the commit for this
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.revision="${COMMIT_HASH}"

# Human-readable title of the image (string)
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.title="MyApplication"

# Default the target version to 0.0.0-SNAPSHOT
ARG gVersion=0.0.0-SNAPSHOT

# Override the version from environment, if present (helpful with CI tools)
ENV gavVersion ${gavVersion}

# Copy application to container's /app folder
COPY /target/myapplication-${gVersion}.jar /app/

# Change ownership to 'nobody' user aka account with least permissions
RUN chown -R nobody:nobody /app/

CMD java -jar /app/myapplication-${gVersion}.jar
```

Comment: Is that the entire exception? Are you sure it isn't caused by another exception, like an error connecting to the database?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mark. Yeah, that is the entire exception i see. I dont find anything saying "could not connect to DB"

Comment: Actually looking at your question again, I see the log says: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed`. That's your actual error. You need to fix the DB connectivity issue.

Comment: After going through logs in deep, i found a different error which could be the root cause for all ===> Unable to load credentials from EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))\n\tat com.amazonaws.auth.EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.java:49)\n\tat com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:118)\n\tat

Comment: Are you using AWS credentials for database connections?